# Move my swap partition into my extended partition

Tags: gparted, disk, partitioning, disk-management

I accidentally created my swap partition outside of my extended partition. Is it possible to move it inside my extended partition? I need to do this because I have used up my limit of 4 primary partitions and would like to make use of my unallocated partition.

Comment: You'll have to repartition disk. You may disable swap (swapoff; later re-enable with swapon) on the actual system and repartition disk as necessary from inside of your actual system or boot livecd and repartition the disk then. Remember to add new partitions to /etc/fstab with mountpoints of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say with certainty without seeing detailed partition table data (as in `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print`. In some cases, though, the [FixParts program](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/), which is part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu, can do the job. The FixParts documentation (just linked) describes the details of how to do it. In a worst-case scenario, you should be able to do it by combining a partition-resizing operation (with GParted) with FixParts.

If you need more help, please edit your question with the specified `fdisk` and/or `parted` output and post a comment to my answer so that I'll see a flag to re-read it.